# android same activity starts after finish()

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm starting activity B for result from activity A.

```
if (model.isPositionClickable(pos)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,  CharacterChooseActivity.class);
        clickedPosition = pos;
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Then in activity B I'm doing the following

```
public class CharacterChooseActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_character_choose);
}

public void characterSelected(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) v;
    String s = (String) b.getText();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("character", s);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}



}
```

And when I'm clicking the button for first time it's starting activity B again. If I'll click the button second time in this new B activity is will start activity B again. And only on the third click it will resume activity A.

Why is that so?
How to get back to activity A after first click?
I think that this is has to do with activity back stack, but I don't know how to change it.

EDIT

I've localized the problem. It has to do with MotionEvent listener and how I'm handling clicks.

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    final int pos = gv.getCellPosition(event.getX(), event.getY());
    int maxPosition = model.getNumberOfColumns() * model.getNumberOfRows();
    if (pos >= 0 && pos < maxPosition) {
        Mode mode = model.getMode();
        switch(mode) {
        case CHAR_SELECT_MODE : inputCharacter(pos); break;
        case WORD_SELECT_MODE : selectcharacter(event, pos); break;
        default : break;
        }
    }       
    return true;    
}

private void selectcharacter(MotionEvent event, int pos) {
    if (event.getActionMasked() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if(!model.isPositionEnabled(pos))
            return;
        else
            if(model.isValidPosition(pos))
                model.setSelected(pos);
    }
    else {
        model.createWord();
    }
}

public void inputCharacter(final int pos) {
    if (model.isPositionClickable(pos)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,  CharacterChooseActivity.class);
        clickedPosition = pos;
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
}
```

I need to be able to handle to different events: OnItemClick and onTouch.

I can do it by adding a new mode to the model to get the controller know, that it should not handling touch events.

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    final int pos = gv.getCellPosition(event.getX(), event.getY());
    int maxPosition = model.getNumberOfColumns() * model.getNumberOfRows();
    if (pos >= 0 && pos < maxPosition) {
        Mode mode = model.getMode();
        switch(mode) {
        case CHAR_SELECT_MODE : inputCharacter(pos); break;
        case WORD_SELECT_MODE : selectCharacter(event, pos); break;
        case INPUT_BLOCKED_MODE: break;
        default : break;
        }
    }       
    return true;    
}
```

But I can't get it work when I have both onItemClick and onTouchListeners. I've tried to return false and super.OnTouchEvent(Event). OnItemClick event still isn't firing.

Comment: Try putting a log in the onCreate of your CharacterChooseActivity, then, watch when it is shown. It should be shown 3 times, as you said _only on the third click it will resume activity A_. The question is : are the 3 logs all shown when you first start you activity B or are they shown when you quit activity B? If this is the first solution, consider posting the code leading to `if (model.isPositionClickable(pos))`

Comment: Well, I've toogled a breakpoint in the onCreate method of CharacterChoosActivity. And it is really stops there 2 times.
PS
Log also shown that onCreate is called two times.

Comment: Do you apply the onClickListener and the onTouch to the same view? Or do you apply onClick to a child of the view on which you apply the onTouch?

Comment: I've applied onItemClickListener and onTouchListener to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know how, I don't now why, but after I've return false in onTouch() OnItemClick was fired.
Previously I've already did that and It somehow wasn't working...

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //[EDIT: Process only when user takes out his finger i.e on ACTION_UP
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            //EDIT]  
            final int pos = gv.getCellPosition(event.getX(), event.getY());
            int maxPosition = model.getNumberOfColumns() * model.getNumberOfRows();
            if (pos >= 0 && pos < maxPosition) {
                Mode mode = model.getMode();
                switch(mode) {
                case CHAR_SELECT_MODE : inputCharacter(pos); break;
                case WORD_SELECT_MODE : selectcharacter(event, pos); break;
                default : break;
                }
            }       
            return true;
        }

        return super.onTouch(v,event);            
    }
```

Bug in your code: onTouchEvent will be triggered for different actions of user. i.e ACTION_DOWN,ACTION_UP,ACTION_MOVE etc. So whenever any of these action triggered you were starting B. We need start B only when user has taken out his finger.

Comment: Sorry! I was returning super.onTouchEvent(..) . Please check edited code.

Comment: The method onTouch(View, MotionEvent) is undefined for the type Activity.

Comment: You have to implement OnTouchListener interface in your activity. And setOnTouchListner reference to the activity via 'this' i.e button.setOnTouchListener(this);

Comment: On touch listener is working perfectly. It's OnItemClickListener is not working in gridview even if I return false from onTouch Event handler.

Comment: In that case you better start a new question as it is completely different from your current bug. Also you haven't mentioned anything about gridview since your first post. People might down vote for your question.

Comment: @Chandan I cannot add return super.onTouch(v, event) without getting an error. Do you know of a way to fix this?